# How to modify meteor users collection name?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I want to use the my collection users
When i `users = new Mongo.Collection('users');`
Then  error : `here is already a collection named "users"`
What should I do？

Comment: Can you give more information on why you want to change the collection name? You are using the ```accounts-base``` package which gives you access to the Meteor.users collection. That's why you can't set up a collection with the same name. Is there are any specific reason you want to change the name?

Comment: In fact, there are two meteor projects that are used `accounts-base`, one of which wants to access the `users` of another project

Answer (score 0):

Actually you already have a collection name 'users' if you see your mongodb collections.

when you install package `'accounts-base'` in your project it will create a collection with 'users' name automatically.

so you can not create a new collection with same name. 
if you want to use '`users`' collection data then simply use `Meteor.userId()` and `Meteor.user()` . Use `console.log(Meteor.user())` to see data.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a second users collection then do:

```
Users = new Mongo.Collection('myusers');
```

or

```
Users = new Mongo.Collection('users2');
```

But this is really not recommended if you're using the accounts package because of the potential confusion, especially if someone else ends up working on your project.

There's also a de facto Meteor convention that collection variables are defined with an initial uppercase letter but are all lower case in mongo as above.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, iIn fact, there are two meteor projects that are used `accounts-base`, one of which wants to access the `users` of another project, you think I should do?

Comment: If they are sharing a mongodb database then you don't need to create a second collection - both apps can share the user collection. This is a common pattern when partitioning Meteor applications.